# Specific Max Sum of the elements of an Int array - C/C++

Tags: algorithm

Let's say we have an array: 7 3 1 1 6 13 8 3 3
I have to find the maximum sum of this array such that:

- if i add 13 to the sum: i cannot add the neighboring elements from each side: 6 1 and 8 3 cannot be added to the sum
- i can skip as many elements as necessary to make the sum max

My algorithm was this:

- I take the max element of the array and add that to the sum
- I make that element and the neighbor elements -1
- I keep doing this until it's not possible to find anymore max

The problem is that for some specific test cases this algorithm is wrong.
Lets see this one:   15 40 45 35

according to my algorithm:

- I take 45 and make neighbors -1
- The program ends

The correct way to do it is 15 + 35 = 50

Comment: What is your algorithm?

Comment: ...  And where is the code

Comment: I'm confused too.  The array has only one sum, so max=min=sum?

Comment: This does not make a lot of sense to be honest. And I don't see why the C/C++ tags are here

Comment: Your approach is a greedy algorithm, which doesn't satisfy the local optimal condition and so cannot always find the solution. You need to use dinamic programming to solve this.

Comment: @Tim I've written what is my algorithm. I had wrong formatting. Check my post again

Comment: @mathematician1975 Ok I removed that C/C++ tags. I added those because those are the languages I work with

Comment: @bolov Could you please give an answer how could i do it with dynamic programming

Comment: @Arlind They would be fine if you had posted your C/C++ code - but with no code, they were pretty pointless

Answer (score 1):

This problem can be solved with [dynamic programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming).

1. Let A be the array, let `DP[m]` be the max sum in `{A[1]~A[m]}`
2. Every element in A only have two status, been added into the sum or not. First we suppose we have determine `DP[1]~DP[m-1]`, now look at `{A[1]~A[m]}`, `A[m]` only have two status that we have said, if `A[m]` have been added into, `A[m-1]` and `A[m-2]` can't be added into the sum, so in add status, the max sum is `A[m]+DP[m-3]` (intention: `DP[m-3]` has been the max sum in `{A[1]~A[m-3]}`), if `A[m]` have not been added into the sum, the max sum is `DP[m-1]`, so we just need to compare `A[m]+DP[m-3]` and `DP[m-1]`, the bigger is `DP[m]`. The thought is the same as mathematical induction.
3. So the DP equation is `DP[m] = max{ DP[m-3]+A[m], DP[m-1] }`，`DP[size(A)]` is the result

The complexity is O(n), pseudocode is follow：

```
 DP[1] = A[1];
 DP[2] = max(DP[1], DP[2]);
 DP[3] = max(DP[1], DP[2], DP[3]);
 for(i = 4; i <= size(A); i++) {
     DP[i] = DP[i-3] + A[i];
     if(DP[i] < DP[i-1])
         DP[i] = DP[i-1];
 }
```

Comment: Could you explain this some more please?

Comment: @Arlind, I have edit my answer, you can read the second point in detail

Answer (score 0):

It's solvable with a dynamic programming approach, taking O(N) time and O(N) space. Implementation following:

```
int max_sum(int pos){

    if( pos >= N){ // N = array_size
        return 0;
    }

    if( visited(pos) == true ){ // if this state is already checked
        return ret[pos];     // ret[i] contains the result for i'th cell
    }

    ret[pos] = max_sum(pos+3) + A[pos] + ret[pos-2]; // taking this item

    ret[pos] = max(ret[pos], ret[pos-1]+ max_sum(pos+1) ); // if skipping this item is better
    visited[pos] = true;
    return ret[pos];
}

int main(){
    // clear the visited array
    // and other initializations
    cout << max_sum(2) << endl; //for i < 2, ret[i] = A[i]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The above problem is max independent set problem (with twist) in a path graph which has dynamic programming solution in O(N).

Recurrence relation for solving it : -

```
Max(N) = maximum(Max(N-3) + A[N] , Max(N-1))
```

Explanation:- IF we have to select maximum set from N elements than we can either select Nth element and the maximum set from first N-3 element or we can select maximum from first N-1 elements excluding Nth element.

Pseudo Code : -

```
Max(1) = A[1];
Max(2) = maximum(A[1],A[2]);
Max(3) = maximum(A[3],Max(2));

for(i=4;i<=N;i++) {

 Max(N) = maximum(Max(N-3)+A[N],Max(N-1));

}
```

Answer (score 0):

As suggested, this is a dynamic programming problem.

First, some notation, Let:

- `A` be the array, of integers, of length `N`
- `A[a..b)` be the subset of `A` containing the elements at index `a` up to 
  but not including `b` (the half open interval).
- `M` be an array such that `M[k]` is the specific max sum of `A[0..k)`
  such that `M[N]` is the answer to our original problem.

We can describe an element of `M` (`M[n]`) by its relation to one or more elements of `M` (`M[k]`) where `k < n`. And this lends itself to a nice linear time algorithm. So what is this relationship?

- The base cases are as follows:

  - `M[0]` is the max specific sum of the empty list, which must be `0`.
  - `M[1]` is the max specific sum for a single element, so must be 
     that element: `A[0]`.
  - `M[2]` is the max specific sum of the first two elements. With only
     two elements, we can either pick the first or the second, so we better
     pick the larger of the two: `max(A[0], A[1])`.
- Now, how do we calculate `M[n]` if we know `M[0..n)`? Well, we have a choice to make:
  Either we add `A[n-1]` (the last element in `A[0..n)`) or we don't. We don't know for
  certain whether adding `A[n-1]` in will make for a larger sum, so we try both and take 
  the max:

  - If we don't add `A[n-1]` what would the sum be? It would be the same as the
     max specific sum immediately before it: `M[n-1]`.
  - If we *do* add `A[n-1]` then we can't have the previous two elements in our 
     solution, but we can have any elements before those. We know that `M[n-1]` and 
     `M[n-2]` *might* have used those previous two elements, but `M[n-3]` definitely
     didn't, because it is the max in the range `A[0..n-3)`. So we get 
     `M[n-3] + A[n-1]`.

  We don't know which one is bigger though, (`M[n-1]` or `M[n-3] + A[n-1]`), so to find
  the max specific sum at `M[n]` we must take the max of those two.

So the relation becomes:

```
M[0] = 0
M[1] = A[0]
M[2] = max {A[0], A[1]}
M[n] = max {M[n-1], M[n-3] + A[n-1]} where n > 2
```

***Note** a lot of answers seem to ignore the case for the empty list, but it is
definitely a valid input, so should be accounted for.*

The simple translation of the solution in C++ is as follows:

*(Take special note of the fact that the size of `m` is one bigger than the size of `a`)*

```c
int max_specific_sum(std::vector<int> a)
{
    std::vector<int> m( a.size() + 1 );

    m[0] = 0; m[1] = a[0]; m[2] = std::max(a[0], a[1]);

    for(unsigned int i = 3; i <= a.size(); ++i)
        m[i] = std::max(m[i-1], m[i-3] + a[i-1]);

    return m.back();
}
```

**BUT** This implementation has a *linear space requirement* in the size of `A`. If you look at the definition of `M[n]`, you will see that it only relies on `M[n-1]` and `M[n-3]` (and not the whole preceding list of elements), and this means you need only store the **previous 3 elements** in `M`, resulting in a *constant space requirement*. (The details of this implementation are left to the OP).